# netbsd: How to read cdrom labels

Tags: netbsd

I'm trying to create a NetBSD image to be used on my opennebula cloud, and for its contextualization I need to look for a disk labeled "CONTEXT", in fact it is a cdrom, usually on debian I would look for it on /dev/disk/by-label, but in NetBSD the story seems to be different, and I tried to use disklabel but I have found only the "fictitious" label on the cdrom:

`NetBSDImage# disklabel /dev/cd0
# /dev/cd0d:
type: ATAPI
disk: iso partition
label: fictitious
flags: removable
bytes/sector: 2048
sectors/track: 100
tracks/cylinder: 1
sectors/cylinder: 100
cylinders: 2
total sectors: 181
rpm: 300
interleave: 1
trackskew: 0
cylinderskew: 0
headswitch: 0           # microseconds
track-to-track seek: 0  # microseconds
drivedata: 0`

4 partitions:
#        size    offset     fstype [fsize bsize cpg/sgs]
 a:       181         0    ISO9660       0             # (Cyl.      0 -      1*)
 d:       181         0        UDF                     # (Cyl.      0 -      1*)
disklabel: boot block size 0
disklabel: super block size 0
disklabel: partitions a and d overlap

I do not understand how can I do the same on NetBSD, checking if there is any disk named "CONTEXT" to mount it.
The plan B is just to mount the cdrom if it is available and check if there is a file called context.sh but I would prefer to do it the right way, by checking the disk name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [file(1)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?file%20%20NetBSD-current) command on the CD-ROM device.

For example, I have a NetBSD 7 iso in my CD-ROM drive:

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/cd0d
/dev/cd0d: # ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'NETBSD_70_BETA' (bootable)
```

The Volume ID here is 'NETBSD_70_BETA'

You can also install isoinfo from pkgsrc (sysutils/cdrtools) and sed/grep the data you need:

```
$ sudo isoinfo -d -i /dev/cd0d
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: NetBSD
Volume id: NETBSD_70_BETA
Volume set id: 
Publisher id: THE_NETBSD_PROJECT
...
```

More info can be found in the [wiki](http://wiki.netbsd.org/guide/rmmedia/#index16h2).